# missing artifact in pom.xml file .And unable to solve the error coming in session and document

Tags: java, maven, gwt, couchdb

I am trying to create the document in couch db using maven . But i am facing problem in my pom file showing the error of missing artifact in dependencies.And also i am facing in creating document in .I have written the code to create the document in couch db,but the session and document showing me error. 
Here is my code pom file:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    DocumentCreating
    DocumentCreating
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
    jar
    ROOT
    Creating Document In Couchdb
    
        
            
                src
                
                    
                
                
                    /*.java
                
            
        
        src
        
            
                maven-war-plugin
                2.4
                
                    
                        
                            war
                        
                    
                    false
                
            
            
                maven-dependency-plugin
                
                    
                        process-sources
                        
                            copy-dependencies
                        
                        
                            war/WEB-INF/lib

```
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <!-- convenience to define GWT version in one place -->
    <gwt.version>2.7.0</gwt.version>
    <!-- tell the compiler we can use 1.5 -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- couchdb dependencies -->



    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opencredo.couchdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>couchdb-si-support</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
        <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>pd4ml</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>pd4ml</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>1.0</version> -->
    <!-- <scope>system</scope> -->
    <!-- <systemPath>${project.basedir}/war/WEB-INF/dependencies/pd4ml.jar</systemPath> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->



    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

here is the code implementation file for creating document:

```
package com.DocumentCreating.server;
import com.DocumentCreating.client.GreetingService;
import com.DocumentCreating.shared.FieldVerifier;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
GreetingService {

    public String greetServer( String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        System.out.println(input);
        Session session=new Session("192.168.1.142",5984);
        Database db=session.getDatabase("testing");
        Document doc=new Document();
        doc.put("name", input);
        db.saveDocument(doc);

        return "hello" + input;
    } 

}
```

Comment: You haven't said what the error is (which dependency is missing)

Comment: error is in these dependcies:

Comment: You don't say! Well, good luck with any help then.

Comment: error are in common-collection,common-beanutils,common-codec,common-httpclient,common-language,common-logging and in net.sf.json-lib..

Comment: That would be a very strange error, because those dependencies seems to be present in Maven central repository; Do you have any kind of proxy configured that might be causing networking issues? Also, editing your answer and copying/pasting the error messages would help your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: can u give me the dependency of couchdb .? because i need it in order to run my code .